# How to add an instance of a custom webpart to a web page using PowerShell?

Tags: web-part, powershell, visual-studio

I found [this article](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/How%20to%20create%20Web%20Part%20instances%20on%20pages%20using%20PowerShell%20and%20SPLimitedWebPartManager.aspx) which does a very good job explaining how to add built in web parts (like the content editor webpart).  Unfortunately when I tried to add my own I couldn't get it to work.  I have the webpart already installed on my sharepoint instance, I have checked the GAC and confirmed that the assembly for my webpart is there, but when I try to run this line:

```
$webpart = New-Object HighlightsTicker.HighlightsTickerPart.HighlightsTickerPart
```

I get the error:

> New-Object : Cannot find type
>   [HighlightsTicker.HighlightsTickerPart.HighlightsTickerPart]: make
>   sure the assembly containing this type is loaded. At
>   C:\Users\amiessler\AppData\Local\Temp\3\8c524086-dcea-4250-a4b9-0722c51e3d8f.ps1:5
>   char:22
>   + $webpart = New-Object <<<<  HighlightsTicker.HighlightsTickerPart.HighlightsTickerPart
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

This is what the code for my HightlightsTickerPart.cs looks like namespace/classname wise:

```
namespace HighlightsTicker.HighlightsTickerPart
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class HighlightsTickerPart : WebPart
    {
```

Do I need to do something differently to get this to work with a custom webpart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to load the assembly containing the web part in your PowerShell Session, if you have not done so already. See below:

http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2010/08/29/how-to-load-net-assemblies-in-a-powershell-session/

I think LoadWithPartialName is the way to go in this case.

Comment: I ended up using `Load` Looks like `LoadWithPartialName` has been deprecated.  Ended up looking like this: `[reflection.assembly]::Load("HighlightsTicker, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ccdee482b415afe7")`